# Is the size of a RAM address word size dependent?

Tags: architecture, ram, word-size

In general my question is how many bytes are located in one RAM address. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215495/one-memory-location-in-a-computer-stores-how-much-data) but I am not sure if is talking about RAM or the hard disk.

So for an example, if I have a program that has the line:

```
byte b = 100;
```

Assume I am running on a 32 bit computer. As I understand it, a 32 bit word size means that the size of most registers, the data bus, and most importantly how much data the CPU can handle at once will all be 32 bits. Does this mean that in one RAM address 32 bits will be used to store my variable b or is modern RAM typically byte addressable?

Comment: RAM is always byte-addressed.

Comment: I thought it was as simple as this. Thanks