# How many bytes are typically held in a single memory address?

Tags: memory, byte, bit, memory-address

I understand that the answer to this question may significantly vary from system to system. But I would like to refine my understanding of how memory on a computer works. I understand that a memory address stores the location of a sequence of bits. But specifically, how many bits (or bytes) are typically held in a specific memory address?

Comment: You can't answer that *specifically*, because it depends on the CPU and OS. There is no *one size fits all* answer to this question. Also, this is a duplicate of several existing questions, such as [One memory location in a computer stores how much data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5215495/62576)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One memory location in a computer stores how much data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215495/one-memory-location-in-a-computer-stores-how-much-data)